# customer id found in stripe and in my database

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

This is how I have customer ID and it has also stripe. It is such that the client has terminated its membership but it lacks that extra to go to the plain users again.

I've tried to do like this:

```
var aktivAbonnent = stripeCustomer.StripeSubscriptionList.Data.FirstOrDefault().Status == "canceled";
```

or try its here:

```
var aktivAbonnent = stripeCustomer.StripeSubscriptionList.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CancelAtPeriodEnd == true && x.Status == "canceled");
```

*If I run this one solution here, so give it to me by my FALSE if*

In my database have i : **cus_8fuid1S7nHeTC3**

```
var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"];
var customerService = new StripeCustomerService(apiKey);
var stripeCustomer = customerService.Get("cus_8fuid1S7nHeTC3");

var aktivAbonnent = stripeCustomer.StripeSubscriptionList.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CancelAtPeriodEnd == true && x.Status == "canceled");
if (aktivAbonnent != null)
{ // SUCCES NOW
```

[image]

[image]

When I click in at the top, so when I come forward to it so I get them this information forward.

```
object:
id: sub_8fuir6wScpUxuE
object: "subscription"
application_fee_percent: null
cancel_at_period_end: true
canceled_at: 1466454056
created: 1466454037
current_period_end: 1466540437
current_period_start: 1466454037
customer: cus_8fuid1S7nHeTC3
discount: null
ended_at: 1466540476
livemode: false
metadata:
plan:
id: 32645fa8bf7abb4a5b5dadfcbae2d2e509343af80446f730e1fba0791fd681bd
object: "plan"
amount: 6000
created: 1466454036
currency: "dkk"
interval: "day"
interval_count: 1
livemode: false
metadata:
Pakkeid: "32645fa8bf7abb4a5b5dadfcbae2d2e509343af80446f730e1fba0791fd681bd"
OrderId: "jkjnf21ts52016"
name: "1 måned(er) løbende (Alm pakke)"
statement_descriptor: null
trial_period_days: null
quantity: 1
start: 1466454037
status: "canceled"
tax_percent: null
trial_end: null
trial_start: null
```

Comment: Do I know anyone that might help me?